# how to replace the "+" & "-" sign form the the database table

Tags: mysql

| title | value |
| --- | --- |
| VVS1+ | 120 |
| VVS1- | 230 |
| VS1 | 870 |
| VS1+ | 210 |
| VS1- | 560 |
| SI1+ | 1240 |

this above table is my data

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(title ,'-',''),'+','') as Title, SUM(value) as Value FROM 'table_name'
```

and I want to remove those signs and then add those value with the similar title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replace logic is fine, but you need to also aggregate by the modified title:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(title, '-', ''), '+', '') AS title, SUM(value) AS value 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY REPLACE(REPLACE(title, '-', ''), '+', '');
```

If you're using MySQL 8+, then you could tighten up the above code slightly:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '[+-]', '') AS title, SUM(value) AS value 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '[+-]', '');
```

Comment: but when i do that i am not able to get the proper result

Comment: Define what "proper" result means here.  Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: The second one is the same logic, and will generate the same result set as the first one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the `group by ` uses the title column by preference, not the alias; use a different alias name